# archlinux makepkg missing dependenies

Tags: python, linux, archlinux

first, I'm not good in English.

I want to create a package for Arch from a python script.

the script isn't for me, developer told me to make an Arch package for him.

this is my PKGBUILD file.

```
# Maintainer: Danial Behzadi <dani.behzi@ubuntu.com>
pkgname='tractor'
pkgver=3.13
pkgrel=1
pkgdesc="Setup an onion routing proxy"
arch=('any')
url="https://framagit.org/tractor/tractor"
license=('GPLv3')
depends=('python' 'tor' 'python-gobject' 'python-psutil'
         'python-requests' 'python-stem' 'python-fire' 'python-pysocks')                                         
makedepends=('python-setuptools')
source=('tractor::git+https://framagit.org/tractor/tractor.git')
md5sums=('SKIP')

prepare(){
        cd "$pkgname"
        python setup.py build
}

package() {
        cd $pkgname
        sudo python setup.py install --root="$pkgdir"
        sudo cp tractor/tractor.gschema.xml /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
        sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
}
```

when I run `makepkg` got this output:

```
==> Making package: tractor 3.13-1 (Thu 14 Jul 2022 01:28:41 PM +0430)
==> Checking runtime dependencies...
==> Missing dependencies:
  -> python-stem
  -> python-fire
  -> python-pysocks
==> Checking buildtime dependencies...
==> ERROR: Could not resolve all dependencies.
```

this packages are available in repositories but I don't know why I get this errors!

if I remove that packages from depends section, makepkg works fine and give me the package, but if I install it and try to run `tractor` I got a python error like this: `Import Error: fire not found`

**UPDATE**

`python-stem`, `python-fire` and `python-pysocks` not installed on my system. I tried to install them but I got an error for installing `python-stem`:

```
(2/2) checking for file conflicts                                   [######################################] 100%
error: failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)
python-stem: /usr/bin/tor-prompt exists in filesystem
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

the package() section updated to this:

```
package() {
        cd $pkgname
        sudo python setup.py install --root="$pkgdir"                                                            
        cp tractor/tractor.gschema.xml $pkgdir/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
        glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
}
```

the `python setup.py install --root="$pkgdir"` should be run by `sudo` otherwise I got `permission denied` error.

now I got this when running `makepkg`:

```
running install_scripts
Installing tractor script to /home/smjt2000/Projects/archpkg/test/pkg/tractor/usr/bin
cp: cannot create regular file '/home/smjt2000/Projects/archpkg/test/pkg/tractor/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/': No such file or directory
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in package().
    Aborting...
```

Comment: Then just install these dependencies. `sudo python` do not use `sudo` in package and do not copy files to `/usr/`!

Comment: @KamilCuk dependencies are installed on my system. I also tried `makepkg -si` but I got that error again. if I don't use sudo, I got `permission denied`. tractor needs the `tractor.gschema.xml` file be in `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/' for working well.

Comment: `tractor needs the tractor.gschema.xml file be in `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/` No, it needs to be at `$pkgdir/usr/anywhere`, not in root. Pacman installs in root. Consider re-reading https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Creating_packages#package() . `dependencies are installed on my system` Yet the missing dependencies message would indicate that they aren't. What is the output of `pacman -Q python-fire`?

Comment: @KamilCuk Oh thank you. I think that `makepkg -si` will install missing dependencies. those three packages not installed on my system. I installed two of them but `python-stem` give me error. I UPDATE the post and put the output there.

Comment: `now I got this` so create the directory, there is no such directory. Typically, you create directories from pkgbuild with `install` command line tool. I guess `glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/` should be a `post_install` in `.install` script. Browse some existing PKGBUILDs in archlinux AUR. And `prepare()` is I think building the software, it should be in `build()`.

Comment: @KamilCuk thanks to you. finally finished the packaging just with one issue, the `tractor.gschema.xml` is located under python site-packages and I should make it to copy this file to /usr/... directory. I don't know how to make it done. is there anyway to publish packages in main Arch repositories like community or I should put it in AUR?

Comment: `usr/... directory. I don't know how to make it done` As said, create the directory. See https://github.com/archlinux/svntogit-packages/blob/packages/boost/trunk/PKGBUILD#L81 . `is there anyway to publish packages in main Arch repositories like community` Och nooo, you would need to be a trusted user. `I should put it in AUR?` No idea what _you should_ do, that's up to you and that developer you are working for. You can also run your own private repository.

Comment: @KamilCuk the problem is someone may have python3.10 and another one may have python3.9. file will locate under `/usr/lib/python3-VER/site-packages/tractor/tractor.gschema.xml`. I don't know how to detect file location to copy it to `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/`

Comment: `have python3.10 and another one may have python3.9` Don't you think someone already had this problem gazillion times? There are hundreds python-* packages - browse PKGBUILD of them and see how others are doing it, then copy it. `I don't know how to detect file location to copy it to` I do not understand, copy to `$pkgdir/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/`